# Removing dataframe from another dataframe which is a filtered subset of the first dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am fighting with the following issue:

Let's say I have the following input dataframe:

```
df
something library                                                     other_info
FOO       NaN                                                         blaa      
BAR       ['bar/libBAR.a', 'bar/libBAR.cpp.so', 'bar/libBARFIGHT.so'] bluu          
MEH       ['meh/libMEH.a', 'meh/libMEH.so', 'meh/libMEH.other.so']    blqq
```

Then, using the `explode` dataframe functionality:

```
df1 = df.explode('library')

something library             other_info
FOO       NaN                 blaa      
BAR       bar/libBAR.a        bluu     
BAR       bar/libBAR.cpp.so   bluu      
BAR       bar/libBARFIGHT.so  bluu      
MEH       meh/libMEH.a        blqq      
MEH       meh/libMEH.so       blqq
MEH       meh/libMEH.other.so blqq
```

Afterwards I am applying filtering with a regex, to create a subset dataframe:

```
regex = '.*/lib.*\.a'
df2 = df1[df1.library.str.contains(regex, regex=True, na=False)]

something library      other_info
BAR       bar/libBAR.a bluu
MEH       meh/libMEH.a blqq
```

So now I am trying to remove the entries that that I've filtered from df1 using a "condition":

creating a condition (True/False serie)

```
condition = df1['library']isin(df2['library'])

something 
FOO       False
BAR       True
BAR       False
BAR       False
MEH       True
MEH       False
MEH       False
```

Whit this condition, I am trying to remove the entries that I want from d1 (without creating new dataframe):

```
d1.drop(d1[condition].index, inplace=True)
```

The result, though is quiet surprising:

```
something library             other_info
FOO       NaN                 blaa
```

So, all of the entries for BAR and MEH have been dropped from the dataframe even though only one row per "something" matched.

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to filter only the "True" rows and can it be done withint the "filter" method usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just filter on `not condition` like so

```
df3 = df1[~condition]
df3
```

produces

```
    something   library             other_info
0   FOO         NaN                 blaa
1   BAR         bar/libBAR.cpp.so   bluu
1   BAR         bar/libBARFIGHT.so  bluu
2   MEH         meh/libMEH.so       blqq
2   MEH         meh/libMEH.other.so blqq
```

does that work for you?

Your original code will work if you update your `explode` statement like so:

```
df1 = df.explode('library', ignore_index = True)
```

which will re-index the dataframe, which means your subsequent manipulations use unique index values not the original ones (which are repeated for rows that were exploded from the same row)

Comment: df1[~condition] works as expected. Thank you!
For your other proposal:
I will have to combine the rows (reverse the explode function) in the future.
if I use the `ignore_index = True` isn't this going to make it harder?

Comment: if the values in the 'something' column are unique originally, then you can always `groupby` on that column after all these manipulations. if not and you need to rely on the original index for that then yes, it would be harder to do if you reset it. So if `df`[~condition]` works for you then I would stick to that

Comment: Yes the values in 'something' are unique before the `.expode()` so I will play around with `groupby`. Thank you!